# What are the keyboard shortcuts in Photos?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, photos, file-management

What keyboard shortcuts are available for actions like zooming, tagging, next picture, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The ones I could find so far:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> Select all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Import from folder
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> New smart album
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Search
- <kbd>Return</kbd> View photo

Function keys:

- <kbd>F9</kbd> Toggle showing sidebar (left panel)
- <kbd>F10</kbd> Toggle showing photo info (right panel)
- <kbd>F11</kbd> Full screen mode

When viewing an image:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> Zoom out (while holding the key)
- <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> Previous or next photo
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> Jump to previous or next photo (while zoomed in)
- <kbd>Space</kbd> Next photo
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Swap "rotate" button to "left", and swap "flip" button to "vertically"
- <kbd>/</kbd> Flag photo
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> Zoom in or out
- <kbd>[</kbd> / <kbd>]</kbd> Rotate photo CCW or CW